# Can't make wget to continue downloading a file

Tags: linux, command-line, download, wget

I am trying to download a big file using wget (4.5 GB). My OS is ubuntu 18.04 LTS

So what did I do? First I went to the folder, in which I want the file to be downloaded. Then I used the following command:

```
wget http://robotics.ethz.ch/~asl-datasets/iros_2017_voxblox/data.bag
```

I tried this many times and it sticks at different points (sometimes at 80MB and other times at 3.9GB... and everything in between).

After googling a bit, I found that if you give it the option -c it will try to resume downloading from where it left of. Then I ran the command:

```
wget -c http://robotics.ethz.ch/~asl-datasets/iros_2017_voxblox/data.bag
```

and I get the response:

> The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.

The file is definitely not completely downloaded.

Any ideas what I can do?

p.s. keep in mind that I am very new when it comes to networks and have no real know how the http protocol works (or most protocols for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to log the output in a file and look for errors when it stops. Below is the command to do that:

`wget -ov ./log1.txt -- http://robotics.ethz.ch/~asl-datasets/iros_2017_voxblox/data.bag`

The log file will be in the same directory where you are executing the command.

Note: `wget -c [url]` will only work if you execute it from the same directory where there is the partially downloaded file!

Also, another command `curl` can be an alternative. Below is the command:

`curl http://robotics.ethz.ch/~asl-datasets/iros_2017_voxblox/data.bag --output data.bag`

Note: do not use `curl` here without the `--output` flag, as I am not aware of the contents of the data.bag, which then might brick your terminal session!

[Update]: log of wget when I tried to download it:
https://pasteboard.co/Hy4pNtE.png

Comment: the log file just states the same thing. It starts downloads, at one point it loses the connection and tries to reconnect. The prints the same message "The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do"

I also tries curl but has the same behavior, more or less.

Comment: I feel you should check the folder where you are downloading the file if it has any other file with the same name and same extension, if yes then delete/move it and then download again. Nevertheless just to check I did try to download the file and almost around 50%  stopped it and then resumed it with `wget -c` and i was successfully able to download it. Please see my updated answer above to check the log.